# ANR in ParseBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-anr-dialog, bootcompleted

I've added Parse pushes to simple android app I've written.
The problem occurs on Nexus5 with Android 5.1

I did everything according to Parse tutorial https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications.
(Everything is correct - rechecked).

Nevertheless when I reboot my Nexus after some time "App not responding" dialog (ANR) pops up, twice.

```
ANR in ru.givealife
PID: 5728
Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 cmp=ru.givealife/com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver (has extras) }
Load: 10.99 / 5.61 / 2.2
CPU usage from 0ms to 5332ms later with 99% awake:
52% 756/system_server: 25% user + 27% kernel / faults: 7035 minor 43 major
...


ANR in ru.givealife
PID: 6994
Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT flg=0x24000010 cmp=ru.givealife/com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver }
Load: 10.17 / 6.49 / 2.76
CPU usage from 57369ms to 0ms ago:
6.7% 756/system_server: 2.6% user + 4% kernel / faults: 527 minor
...
```

I googled the problem, but nothing helped (StackOverflow is always the last resort for me).
Parse guys, can you help me here please?

Comment: Did you ever find out what this problem was? I have similar issue, where if I launch my app from android studio and my phone is locked the app ANR's, when the phone is unlocked everything works as expected.

Comment: @p.streef No, I didn't. Just waited for next Parse lib update..

Comment: Is it fixed in the latest then? Might look into updating if it is.

Comment: @p.streef I don't remember really:) in any case it's better to have an up-to-date version

Comment: Yes it is, but last time i tried to update the facebook sdk + parse sdk did not work together because they used different bolts libs which conflicted.. So I had to roll back. It's not a really bit issue for me currently, but it's one of those things that would be nice to fix. I'll look into if the fb sdk is using the new bolts yet.